# Get param from URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Using Rails 3.1. I have some pages that render same layout, except the contents are based on types:

```
near_england.html.erb
near_scotland.html.erb
```

So usually the full URLs are:

```
http://localhost/shops/near_england
http://localhost/shops/near_scotland
```

I could have constructed the URL as follows:

```
http://localhost/shops/near?country=england
http://localhost/shops/near?country=scotland
```

And make my query easier by getting the parameters, but I am such a SEO freak that I think `near_england` and `near_scotland` would be better in SEO.

Is there any way that I can strip off the `nearby_` and return `england` as a param so that I can put this in my query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a custom route, mapping to a single view. Add something like this in your route definition:

```
match "near_:country" => "countries#near"
```

In your action, you can retrieve the parameter using `params[:country]`

Comment: Can I create a `near.html.erb` and append the `country` behind it, instead of creating each `near_country.html.erb` individually?

Comment: Yes, in the example I gave, the route will execute the `near` method in the `countries` controller. You can then redirect to the same view for each country, and need only one `near.html.erb`